# WSO2 MI 4.1.0 opensource build issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm building WSO2 MI 4.1.O version to generate binaries and I'm getting an error.

```
Cmd> mvn clean install -U
 Failed to execute goal on project org.wso2.micro.integrator.core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.ei:org.wso2.micro.integrator.core:bundle:4.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.wso2.carbon.crypto:org.wso2.carbon.crypto.api:jar:1.1.3:
```

can anyone suggest?

Comment: What repo are you building?

Comment: Hi , I downloaded source code from https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v4.1.0.

Comment: I working for build and generate open source for use community edition in dev environment as PoC

Answer (score 0):

The following steps work if you just want to build the distribution. I'm skipping all the tests here.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator.git 

cd micro-integrator

git checkout v4.1.0

mvn clean install -DskipTests -Dmaven.test.skip=true -U
```

**Environment**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
Apache Maven 3.6.3
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks 
Can you share Enviroment for V 4.2.0

Comment: @user917846 same environment should work for 4.2 as well.

Comment: Hi Im getting 404 error on below  
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/equinox/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata/2.2.0.v20130523-1557/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata-2.2.0.v20130523-1557.pom